# How to know if the user has reached the edges of Webview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I'm trying to develop an app based on the idea of the Twitter for iPad, with sliding panels (for this, I'm using stackscrollView https://github.com/Reefaq/StackScrollView).

I have a UIWebview inside a UIScrollView, what I need is a way to find if the user has "reached the edge" of the UIWebView. I mean, I want user being able to pan around the web view, zoom in/out. But, I would like to find a way to get noticed when some of the edges of the web view has been reached. When that happens, I don't want the webView to bounce (that's simple, bounce = FALSE), instead, I want that starting from this point, the ScrollView start to respond to the touch (Even with the finger of the user inside the webView).

Basically: I wanna to the same thing that Twitter for iPad does when it opens a panel to show a site: allow us to zoom in/out, panning around, and, when the edge is reached, the panel is swiped.

I think the way to go is using scrollView property of the UIWebview, but I don't know exactly how.

Any idea?